# Intensity of an Electromagnetic Wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

What happens to the intensity of an electromagnetic wave if the amplitude of the electric field is halved?

Comment: Intensity of an electromagnetic wave  is directly proportional to the square of amplitude of the wave.

Answer (score 1):

The intensity if an electromagnetic wave is the square of the amplitude $I=A^2$, which means that if $A_{new}=\frac{A}{2}$ the intensity becomes $I_{new}=\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)^2=\frac{A^2}{4}$ and we can see that the intensity is one quarter of what it was before.

$$ \frac{I_{new}}{I}=\frac{\left(\frac{A^2}{4}\right)}{A^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$ which gives us $$I_{new}=\frac{I}{4}$$